# $\cos(2\pi f nT +2\pi N_n) =\ cos(2\pi f nT)$ and more, why?

Tags: signal-processing, sampling

I am studying signals and systems and this came up?

Could someone explain why is $\cos(2\pi f nT +2\pi N_n)$  equal to $\ cos(2\pi f nT)$?

The book says: "because $N_n$ is an integer"

I am wondering how does that explain the equation?

Same with the following:

$e^{i2\pi Nf_snT}=1$

in

[snippet from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvzZ7.png)

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the picture below;

[image: Cosine Graph]

Can you see that between $0$ and $2\pi$ has a specific behaviour, but repeats after the $2\pi$? This is because the cosine function has a *period* of $2\pi$. That is to say, $$\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2k\pi)$$

for $k\in \Bbb{Z}.$ To illustrate this, plugging $0$ into the cosine gives $$\cos(0) = 1 = \cos(0 + 2\pi) = \cos(0 + 4\pi) = \dots.$$